# Extract Xpath value from IwebElement

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I need the value of an Xpath from Iwebelement. Can someone help me out? PFB code

```
IWebElement webElement;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(webElement.GetAttribute("id")))
            {
                searchprop.Add("Id", webElement.GetAttribute("id"));
            }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(webElement.GetAttribute("XPath")))
        {
            searchprop.Add("XPath", webElement.GetAttribute("XPath"));
        }
```

Here,it is obvious that I can't get the Xpath value using "webElement.GetAttribute("XPath")" Since Xpath is not an attribute.Similar to the ID value I need the Xpath as well.So how can I get that?

Comment: You need to provide or create the xpath locator... Or get it using browser developer tools.

Comment: Why do you need the XPath for an element you've already found?

Comment: I'm actually selecting the control from web browser which should give me all the control information(ID,ClassName,Xpath).This information i;ll be placing in app.Once the user selects any of the control from my app,I should be able to highlight the selected control in browser using Xpath/ID/ClassName.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this method will solve your problem.

```
public String GetElementXPath(IWebDriver driver, IWebElement element)
{
    String javaScript = "function getElementXPath(elt){" +
                            "var path = \"\";" +
                            "for (; elt && elt.nodeType == 1; elt = elt.parentNode){" +
                                "idx = getElementIdx(elt);" +
                                "xname = elt.tagName;" +
                                "if (idx > 1){" +
                                    "xname += \"[\" + idx + \"]\";" +
                                "}" +
                                "path = \"/\" + xname + path;" +
                            "}" +
                            "return path;" +
                        "}" +
                        "function getElementIdx(elt){" +
                            "var count = 1;" +
                            "for (var sib = elt.previousSibling; sib ; sib = sib.previousSibling){" +
                                "if(sib.nodeType == 1 && sib.tagName == elt.tagName){" +
                                    "count++;" +
                                "}" +
                            "}" +
                            "return count;" +
                        "}" +
                        "return getElementXPath(arguments[0]).toLowerCase();";
    return (String)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(javaScript, element);
}
```